# calculate score if something true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where i take in some data from a user, everything is working fine. I am trying to build a score in the model where if some data is present the score goes up, and i am trying something like this:

```
def score
 score = 0
 if self.moving = true 
  score += 5
 end
end
```

Here is my form and the 'moving' column is a boolean:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.select :moving, [['Yes', true], ['No',false]], {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

What happens is when I try this, when it is true 'yes' the score has 5 added but if i change it to false, I would like the score to go back down to the original score which has been built.

Also the score should be stored in a column which has been created in the database, i tried using `self.score` but it does not seem to work?

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you need `if moving == true`. Note the double equals sign. Or simply `if moving`

Comment: `if self.moving == true update_attributes(score: score + 5) end` - try this

Comment: thanks it required '==' not '='

Comment: If an answer helped, please accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning (single equals sign)

```
if moving = true
  puts "moving"
end
```

This will always execute the if block because the return value of the assignment is true)

Instead You should compare (double equals sign)

```
if moving == true
  puts "moving"
end
```

But this is still a bit to complicated because you first compare a boolean to another boolean and then pass the result of this comparison to the if clause. This looks a bit like this:

```
result = moving == true
if result
  puts "moving"
end
```

Instead you can just write:

```
if moving
  puts "moving"
end
```

and you could even use the if as statement modifier:

```
puts "moving" if moving
```

Methods that return booleans are usually appended a "?" to indicate this behavior:

```
def moving?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

in if condition you were used = use == instead of it

```
if self.moving == true 
 score += 5
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing wrong, try it like :

```
def score
 score = 0
 if self.moving == true 
  score += 5
 end
end
```

as `=` is used for assignment and is assigning true to your attribute every time but you want it to just compare the value with `==`.

Comment: probably he doesn't need else part based on question.